# Trying to deploy from travis-ci to gh-pages

Tags: travis-ci, github-pages

I'm trying to follow [this](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/07/11/publishing-to-github-pages-from-travis-ci/) set of instructions.

My travis log is [here](https://travis-ci.org/zaun/riot-ui/builds/152576473).

```
0.01s$ openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_4b2755af321b_key -iv $encrypted_4b2755af321b_iv -in etc/deploy.enc -out ~/.ssh/publish-key -d
before_install.2
0.00s$ chmod u=rw,og= ~/.ssh/publish-key
before_install.3
0.00s$ echo "Host github.com" >> ~/.ssh/config
before_install.4
0.00s$ echo "  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/publish-key" >> ~/.ssh/config
before_install.5
0.00s$ git --version
git version 1.8.5.6
before_install.6
0.01s$ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:zaun/riot-ui.git
$ git fetch origin -f gh-pages:gh-pages
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.253.112' to the list of known hosts.
Enter passphrase for key '/home/travis/.ssh/publish-key': 
Done: Job Cancelled
```

The job hangs with `/home/travis/.ssh/publish-key`. The key has no password. Hitting `Enter` would make the script continue.

My `before_install` step to deal with the key is this:

```
before_install:
  - openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_4b2755af321b_key -iv $encrypted_4b2755af321b_iv -in etc/deploy.enc -out ~/.ssh/publish-key -d
  - chmod u=rw,og= ~/.ssh/publish-key
  - ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  - echo "Host github.com" >> ~/.ssh/config
  - echo "  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/publish-key" >> ~/.ssh/config
  - git --version
  - git remote set-url origin git@github.com:zaun/riot-ui.git
  - git fetch origin -f gh-pages:gh-pages
```

What am I doing wrong? how do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ssh agent instead.

```
addons:
  ssh_known_hosts: github.com

before_script:
- openssl aes-256-cbc -K $encrypted_4b2755af321b_key -iv $encrypted_4b2755af321b_iv -in etc/deploy.enc -out publish-key -d
- chmod 600 publish-key
- eval `ssh-agent -s`
- ssh-add publish-key
```

And it can be more secure to do this as late as possible to avoid third party scripts to expose your keys. I personally do this in my `after_success` script, just before using git commands.

You can have a look at [this repository](https://github.com/djacquel/jekyll-twitter-bootstrap-sass) for a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

If `git` is waiting for input, you can try feeding it a newline:

```
before_install:
  ⋮
  - echo | git fetch origin -f gh-pages:gh-pages
```